# Understand Bindings in Components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bindings, angularjs-components

I don't get the binding in angular [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). I have reworked this [material FAB demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial) to a component. So there is no `ng-controller` directive anymore. However I cannot make the bindings of `bindings: {isOpen: '='}` to work. I get the following error:

> Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'isOpen' used with directive 'tsButton' is non-assignable!

The code looks like this:

```
<div ng-cloak>
<md-fab-speed-dial
        md-open="$ctrl.isOpen"
        ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.isOpen=true"
        ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.isOpen=false">
    <!-- buttons and trigger -->
</md-fab-speed-dial>
```

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('trip')
    .component('tsButton', {
    templateUrl: "app/component/button.component.html",
    controller: ButtonController,
    });

    function ButtonController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.isOpen = false;
    };
}
})();
```

If I omit the `bindings: {isOpen: '='}` then `md-open="$ctrl.isOpen"` is not propagated.

A workaround is to define methods for `ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.open()"` and `ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.close()"` that in controller assign the correct boolean to `vm.isOpen`. But as I say it is just a workaround that makes the code longer,  among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isOpen: '='` was not working because I was giving it a primitive value. For this to work it had to be a **reference** of course.